# jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: java, c++, gcc, java-native-interface

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jni/simple-example-of-using-the-java-native-interface.html), and at step 5, I am getting the following output from GCC:

```
    HelloWorld.c:1:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from HelloWorld.c:3:
    HelloWorld.h:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
    HelloWorld.c:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
```

I know that he include directories vary from system to system, so I tried to adapt the command accordingly, but I cannot seem to find the correct directory on my system. I am using Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Comment: +1 for `no matter how simple, it should be beneficial to others as well.`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Open up a terminal and type:

```
locate jni.h
```

That should tell you where every file called jni.h is on your system.  I am on ubuntu 11.04, and it's located at:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/jni.h
```

You may also need to get it from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

should do the trick if you don't have it installed.

Comment: Now that I have fonud jni.h, what should I do in order to finish my bulid?  Add it to my path?

Comment: Install `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`, but still `locate jni.h` gives me nothing

Answer (score 6):

`jni.h` lives with JDK. For me it is: `jdk1.6.0_25/include/`.

And by default, I don't think Ubuntu would have JDK with development libraries, so download [latest JDK version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html) from Oracle and install it somewhere.

Or you can install `openjdk` as @Leif suggested if it works on 10.04 LTS. Although, I personally, prefer the one from Sun/Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre-lib
```

Now, you have a headers into /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include

For OpenJDK 6:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre-lib
```