# how to make jni.h be found?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classpath

In Ubuntu 12.04, I have jdk7 from sun/oracle installed. When `locate jni.h`, it prints multiple locations

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include/jni.h
...
```

In the header file generated by JDK, there is `include <jni.h>`, and currently it complains

```
fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory.
```

In my `Makefile`, there is no specification of locations where `jni.h` is. And I am asking if possible to configure certain system parameter to make path of `jni.h` (say, `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include/jni.h`) to be known when being compiled.

Comment: Add `-I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include` to compiler flags.

Comment: is there any system-wise configuration for path of jni.h, so that no need to specify compile option everytime it gets compiled.

Comment: Possible setting `JVM_HOME` environment variable and referring to it from the makefile (I _think_): `-I$JVM_HOME/include`

Comment: The next stage after this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804253/jni-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to tell your compiler where is the include directory. Something like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include
```

But it depends on your makefile.

Comment: Locate jni.h returns me nothing. I have java 1.7 installed on Ubuntu 13.04 machine.

Comment: To generalize jdb's solution: first set an environment $JAVA_HOME to point to your desired jdk folder. Then make sure to include the path $JAVA_HOME/include in your include paths for the gcc call.

Answer (score 33):

It needs both `jni.h` and `jni_md.h` files, Try this

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include \
  -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include/linux filename.c
```

This will include both the broad JNI files and the ones necessary for linux

Comment: Hey! I'm on mac and `gcc -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/include/` gives me following error: `clang: error: no input files`

Answer (score 18):

Installing the OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) should fix your problem.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-X-jdk
```

This should make you able to compile without problems.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package openjdk-X-jdk`

Comment: You're supposed to replace the X with the java version you need.

Answer (score 12):

I usually define my JAVA_HOME variable like so:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java/
```

Therein are the necessary include files. I sometimes add the below to my .barshrc when I compile a lot of things that need it.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following code:

```
make -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk*/include
```

where jdk* is the directory name of your jdk installation (e.g. jdk1.7.0).

And there wouldn't be a system-wide solution since the directory name would be different with different builds of JDK downloaded and installed. If you desire an automated solution, please include all commands in a single script and run the said script in Terminal.

Comment: This answer (though not voted) is the correct solution to this question.

Comment: Locate jni.h returns me nothing. I have java 1.7 installed on Ubuntu 13.04 machine.

Comment: I suspect this is going to fail hard if there is more than one jdk installation

Comment: On Fedora, to locale `jni.h`, type `sudo dnf repoquery --installed -l java-latest-openjdk-devel`

Answer (score 7):

For me it was a simple matter of being sure to include the JDK installation (I'd only had the JRE). My `R CMD javareconf` output was looking like:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_191
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : not present
Java headers gen.:
Java archive tool:

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    :
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'conftest.o' failed
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java library path:
JNI cpp flags    :
JNI linker flags :
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

And indeed there was no `include` file in my `$JAVA_HOME`. Very simple remedy:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
```

(note that this is specifically intended to install the `openJDK` and *not* the one from Oracle)

Afterwards all is well:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_191
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Comment: after I did the steps you recommended I also added following lines to my Cmakelists.txt file:

`include_directories(/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux)

link_directories(/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server)`

then deleted the Cmake cache and built the project again, then everything went well

Answer (score 5):

Setting JAVA_INCLUDE_DIR to where jni.h is located should solve your problem (setting CPPFLAGS did not work for me)

Assuming it is /usr/lib64/java/include;

```
export JAVA_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib64/java/include
```

Comment: I use build.xml for some older project and this didn't work for me, I had to provide <arg value="-I/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.152/include"/> and             <arg value="-I/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.152/include/linux"/> to make it working

Answer (score 3):

Above answers give you a hardcoded path solution.  This is bad on so many levels (java version change, OS change, etc).

Cleaner solution is to add:

```
JAVA_HOME = $(shell dirname $$(readlink -f $$(which java))|sed 's^jre/bin^^')
```

near the top of your makefile, then add:

```
-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include
```

To your include flags.

I am posting this because I ran into the same problem and spent too much time googling for wrong answers (I am building an app on multiple platforms so the build environment needs to be transportable).

Comment: Do you mean I should add `-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include` to make.sh? Doing that gave me an error.

Comment: What error?  If you follow the steps I outlined, there should be no error, unless JAVA_HOME is not defined (which might happen for a non-supported install of java).  Also, is your default make shell sh or bash?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: I was using cmd :| .

Comment: cmd???  That's Windows.  Maybe I should be more clear and say that this will work with different **Linux** OSs.  Also, the original question was Linux based, no mention of Windows.

Comment: @Promod This can't be for real.

Comment: This isn’t right either, some versions have an extra subdirectory others lack :(

Comment: I'm using `JAVA_HOME="$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))"`

Answer (score 1):

None of the posted solutions worked for me.

I had to `vi` into my Makefile and edit the path so that the path to the `include` folder and the OS subsystem (in my case, `-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux`) was correct.  This allowed me to run `make` and `make install` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on Ubuntu:

```sh
#X means 6,7,8...
apt install openjdk-X-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, tried all this, finally installing the defaults helped me.

```
$ sudo apt install default-jre
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
Java version     : 11.0.21
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: 
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0’
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux      -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-H0vbME/r-base-4.3.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Even though,

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but I don't care.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this applies in this case, but sometimes the file got deleted for unknown reasons, copying it again into the respective folder should resolve the problem.