# rJava installation in R on debian

Tags: r, rjava

After updating to R 3.0.1 on a Debian 64-bit machine, the rJava package does not want to install.

configuration failed, so sudo R CMD javareconf [this worked on another debian machine]. however it does not work here, has anybody else had this problem? [see terminal output below]

```
henk@crunchbang:~$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_18
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function ‘main’:
conftest.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘JNI_CreateJavaVM’
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib64/R
Done.

# check java
henk@crunchbang:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

java environment:

```
henk@crunchbang:~$ aptitude search "?provides(java-runtime)"
i A default-jre                            - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime        
i A default-jre-headless                   - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headle
p   gcj-4.4-jre                            - Java runtime environment using GIJ/classpath    
p   gcj-4.4-jre-headless                   - Java runtime environment using GIJ/classpath (he
p   gcj-jre                                - Java runtime environment using GIJ/classpath    
p   gcj-jre-headless                       - Java runtime environment using GIJ/classpath (he
i A openjdk-6-jre                          - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT         
i A openjdk-6-jre-headless                 - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headles
i   sun-java6-jre                          - Sun Java(TM) Runtime Environment (JRE) 6 (archit
```

Comment: This question looks pretty much the same, maybe updating to openjdk-7-* solves your issue as well. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438073/unable-to-install-rjava-in-r-3-0-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried that option, but it results in the same error. Updating to openjdk somehow does not work [sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre] : 'not available but referred by another package'.

Comment: `jni.h: No such file or directory` does not look good; make sure you really do have the complete SDK installed. Also consider `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava` as we provide a pre-built package for you.

Comment: Dirk, i have run sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava, but no lift off yet. aalso ran through synaptic but did not see anything additional that i can install. there was no problem before - could this be a conflict between openjdk and sun-java?

Answer (score 3):

I took these steps (on an EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04 and RStudio-Server) to install the R package `qdap` which requires `rJava`:
(I'm probably quoting other sources here and there and I don't remember from where, but thanks.)

Install these repositories from http://sites.psu.edu/theubunturblog/cran2deb4ubuntu/

(debian: http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/cran2deb/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u 
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Java:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
ls /usr/lib/jvm
```

Set a system-wide environment variable for Java:

```
sudo joe /etc/profile.d/javaenvvar.sh
```

which contains:

```
# JAVA environment variable
# for openjdk-7-jdk in order to use the R package `qdap`.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then exit BASH and sign in again. Check your path changes:

```
echo $PATH
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Then:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Should return:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_65
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
```

Create the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` with the following entries:

```
/usr/lib/jvm//usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm//usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Then install `rJava` from those new repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

That just installed `rJava` to `/usr/lib/R/site-library` which is accessible to all users of RStudio-Server, hopefully.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Hopefully, there's only one java installed.

Update R packages:

```
sudo R
> packageStatus()
> update.packages()
```

Install R packages system wide (still within sudo R):

```
> install.packages("qdap", lib="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
```

Reset RStudio-Server:
Sign out of RStudio-Server first.

```
sudo rstudio-server stop
sudo rstudio-server start
```

Sign back in to RStudio-Server.

If you get a memory error, try detaching some packages.
The EC2 t2-micro has only 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the solution was updating to openjdk-7-*  and use `update-alternatives --config java`    to set the java-7-openjdk path.