# R CMD javareconf not finding jni.h

Tags: java, r, rjava

I'm trying to install rJava in a docker container based on debian (jessie) with Anaconda.

As root, I did

```
$ apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  default-jdk default-jre libicu-dev
```

Then

```
$ R CMD javareconf 
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_121
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/conda/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux -I/opt/conda/include    -fpic  -I/opt/conda/include  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
/opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:133: recipe for target 'conftest.o' failed
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /opt/conda/lib/R
Done.
```

But jni.h is right in the JDK:

```
# find /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/ -name jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/include/jni.h
```

It just doesn't look like `javareconf` is finding it.  And, if I look at all the variables I could set with javareconf, like JAVA_HOME, I don't see the ability to set JNI cpp flags, which would need the right includes.

I've seen [various](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202578567-Unable-to-install-rJava-package-on-OpenSUSE-13-2) [posts](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/7340) around the Internet of this problem, but no solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing)

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure if an answer has been confirmed here, but I would point everyone to this [article](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/02/installing-rjava-on-ubuntu/) by Andrew Collier.

What he recommends:

**(1) Updating all repositories**

```bsh
sudo apt update -y
```

**(2) Being sure JRE and JDK 8 are installed**

```bsh
sudo apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

**(3) Then, as many users have said already, pointing R to java with an explicit path to JDK 8**

```bsh
sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

The specific Java package does not matter too much as long as it has all the necessary compiled contents within the /include directory.

```bsh
user@laptop:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/
classfile_constants.h  jdwpTransport.h  jvmticmlr.h  linux
jawt.h                 jni.h            jvmti.h
```

For more on this, I would recommend *[**how to make jni.h be found?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found)* for going about locating/compiling this directory correctly.

Comment: Not pointing to an explicit path was the problem in my case. This solution worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 using R 3.6.3.

Answer (score 16):

R is looking at different location:

```
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux
```

I experienced similar problem, but everything is fine after installing jdk:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: it might be useful to check first if jdk is installed but not correctly referenced, see Damiano Fantini`s answer. If not your way is very valuable, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Had the same issue. Fixed by specifying the path to the Java folder. Briefly, after installing Java you may get a line like this.

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in auto mode
```

I specified that path as JAVA_HOME argument when calling javareconf, as follows.

```
sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: wow this saved me after like 3 hours of browsing through R, Java, rJava and macOS questions... I had exported my JAVA_HOME but when i called R CMD javareconf it was still using a different path.

Comment: Using Java 8, the following command worked for me: `sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64`. (I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436618/2251463 to install Java 8 on Debian 10 Buster).

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by editing the java-config file

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/R/etc/javaconf

set the correct JAVA_HOME in this row:
: ${JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk-9.0.1}
```

Answer (score 3):

I already had Java 11 on ubuntu 18.04 but had to install jdk-11.0.1 following this guide: https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-11-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-18-10/

I then changed JAVA_HOME in javaconf, just like @Spanska Forteva

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/R/etc/javaconfIn javaconf
```

I found that the path to an old version of java was still specified.

```
## Versions from settings when configure was run
: ${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}
: ${JAVA_CPPFLAGS=~autodetect~}
: ${JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~autodetect~}
: ${JAVA_LIBS=~autodetect~}
```

I changed the path to JAVA_HOME to my newly installed jdk:

```
: ${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1}
```

Then ran the CMD with the path to jni.h specified:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/include/jni.h
```

The last bit might not be needed, it should be able to look in that folder anyway, but that is what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and could finally fix it. After a lot of searching, this worked for me (I basically followed the guide here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html):

- downloading and unpacking the JDK (jdk1.8.0_201) to /usr/java/
- downloading and unpacking the JRE (jre1.8.0_201) to /usr/java/ (not sure if I needed this step but I did it in previous attempts to solve this problem)
- Informing Ubuntu of the new java using appropriate versions

For this I ran:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java" 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javac" 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javaws" 1
```

followed by

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java

$ sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javac

$ sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javaws
```

Then I could finally see my java in the alternatives in

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

where I selected the newly installed java. Then I ran

```
 sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/
```

in which I specified again my java jdk path explicitely. After this finished successfully I was able to install rJava in Rstudio which I needed to install glmulti.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to run

```
R CMD javareconf
```

as `su`, just `sudo` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 22.04** user, `openjdk-19-jdk` & `openjdk-19-jre` are available.
Installing these fix the issue as well.
So better use the latest available version:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y openjdk-19-jdk openjdk-19-jre
sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64/
```

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04 this appears to be the solution. I tried most other suggestions before finding this, but this is the only think that worked.