# Fatal Error: 'jni.h' file not found on Mac OSX 10.15.7

Tags: gcc, makefile, swig, java-home

I've tried to run an old java program with some libraries in C. While running `make` command,I kept encounter this error which I believe is related to [JAVA_HOME setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found)

```
swig/main_6_comp_wrap.c:154:10: 

fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
#include <jni.h>
          ^~~~~~~
```

After several attempts of installation with JDK, swig, and gcc with Homebrew, it didn't work out. I am pretty sure jni.h file is located in include folder of **JAVA_HOME**.

```
JAVA_HOME   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/
JDK_HOME    = $(JAVA_HOME)
JRE_HOME    = $(JAVA_HOME)

SWIG        = swig
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS          = -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -fno-common \
          -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/
BUILDLIB    = gcc -shared
LIB6        = java/classes/libC6_comp_backend.jnilib
LIB21       = java/classes/libC21_comp_backend.jnilib
```

System: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
swig: 3.0.12
gcc: 10.2.0

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/` with `-I$JAVA_HOME/include` in CFLAGS as a minimum. You may also need to add `-I$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin`.

You will also need to change the paths used to link the `.jnilib`