# 'jni.h' file not found

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm getting this error in my Mac, Java 11.

I've gone through all the similar questions in stack overflow. They suggest to set JAVA_HOME properly. I think I have configured properly and ensured jni.h is present in the directory.

My environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/selvakumar/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/include
```

**Complete ERROR**

```
apples-MacBook-Pro:wrapper-java selvakumar$ cmake --build ./build/cmake --target quickjs-java-wrapper -j 6
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp.o 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -DCONFIG_BIGNUM -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2021-03-27\" -Dquickjs_java_wrapper_EXPORTS -I/include -I/include/darwin -g -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp.o -c /Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp
/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_context_jni.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp.o 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -DCONFIG_BIGNUM -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2021-03-27\" -Dquickjs_java_wrapper_EXPORTS -I/include -I/include/darwin -g -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/quickjs-java-wrapper.dir/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp.o -c /Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp
In file included from /Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.cpp:4:
/Users/selvakumar/newworkspace/quickjs-wrapper/native/cpp/quickjs_wrapper.h:15:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Still getting the error. I'm not sure what am I missing here.

**Background:**
I'm trying to use quickjs in java using https://github.com/HarlonWang/quickjs-wrapper. Getting this error while running the command `cmake --build ./build/cmake --target quickjs-java-wrapper -j 6`

Please note that Nashorn is deprecated. Therefore I didn't use it.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable and then running cmake from scratch.

Comment: Are you able to execute the `java` command?

Comment: Provide the complete error message copied into your question, with some context lines to understand what is being executed when the error happens.

Comment: Edited the question with complete error. @Reilas Yes, Java command is working and Java programs are running as usual

Comment: when you execute `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the terminal where you start `cmake` does it really output the correct folder?

Comment: Or maybe a better check: when you do a `ls $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/` - does it contain the `jni.h`? Where it looks for that is configured in `wrapper-java/src/main/CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your edit proves that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable was not set when you ran `cmake` to generate the build system.
Just to be sure, nuke your build directory and run `cmake` again *with* the environment variable present:

```
$ rm -rf build/cmake
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home
$ cmake -B build/cmake .
$ cmake --build build/cmake --target quickjs-java-wrapper -j 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question and answer, to an similar inquiry.
[how to make jni.h be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found).

It appears you need to provide the `include` directory to `cmake`.
See, this question and answer, [How to properly add include directories with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake)

Comment: The CMake files in the linked project [do contain include_directories statements](https://github.com/HarlonWang/quickjs-wrapper/blob/main/wrapper-java/src/main/CMakeLists.txt#L18-L19), but they are dependent on an environment variable.